# Normalize speech features per dimensions or across dimensions

Tags: audio, speech-processing, speech

I am working on pipelines for audio processing (audio features that will go into a neural net to create some embeddings).

We are using two features : Filter banks, or MFCC.

I was wondering what was the good approach with normalization :

Should we normalize those frames on each dimension (each frequency / mfcc coefficient), or normalize across all dimensions ?

This could lead to important differences in the relative importance of features .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good starter would be to aggregate those features across your frames into one single feature vector, compute the mean and standard deviation and perform [z-score normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

Comment: what do you mean by aggregate those features across frames into one single features ?

Comment: By that I mean, I simply mean use your features across all the frames to calculate the mean and standard deviation to then perform z score normalization. Sorry if my earlier explanation was a little confusing.

Comment: So my question was exactly about this : Do we calculate mean and standard deviation across all dimension (features), or per dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, we divide the entire audio signal into many frames and calculate the features for each frame. After doing this we have a vector of features and on this vector of features different statistics like Mean, Standard Deviations are applied. In case of normalization, it is preferable to do it for the entire signal and then divide into frames.

I recommend you to go through [Audio Signal Classification Blogs in TowardsDatascience](http://towardsdatascience.com).